# Question re Maxima, Magma and/or Sage computational language capabilities

Tags: mathematica, computer-algebra

I was in touch with Mathematica development team and they indicated that currently Mathematica is not capable to determine whether

$$ Sum[Binomial[n - 1, n - i] Sum[Binomial[k + i, i] Binomial[n - 1, n - k], {k, 0, n}], {i, 0, n}] $$

= ?

$$ (-1)^n*((-4*n^2 - 16*n - 28)*JacobiP[-1 + n, -1 - 2*n, 2, -1/2] + JacobiP[-2 + n, -2*n, 3, -1/2]*(3 + n)*(-1 + n))*4^n/(48*(1 + n)*n) $$

In the standard scientific notation above sums expression looks like following:

$$ Sum_{i=0..n} (C(n-1,n-i)*Sum_{k=0..n} (C(k+i,i)*C(n-1,n-k))) $$

Please note that numerically Mathematica seems to be confirming that both expressions give the same numerical values per following:

```mathematica
Table[ (-1)^n*((-4*n^2 - 16*n - 28)*JacobiP(-1 + n, -1 - 2*n, 2, -1/2) + JacobiP(-2 + n, -2*n, 3, -1/2)*(3 + n)*(-1 + n))*4^n/(48*(1 + n)*n), {n, 1, 15}] 
{2,14,106,838,6802,56190,470010,3968310,33747490,288654574,2480593546,21400729382,185239360178,1607913963614,13991107041306} 

Table[Sum[Binomial[n - 1, n - i] Sum[Binomial[k + i, i] Binomial[n - 1, n - k], {k, 0, n}], {i, 0, n}], {n, 1, 15}] 
{2,14,106,838,6802,56190,470010,3968310,33747490,288654574,2480593546,21400729382,185239360178,1607913963614,13991107041306}
```

but there's a need in a symbolic proof.

Do Magma and/or Maxima and/or Sage have such capability?

Comment: It would help to improve the question if you stated the problem in standard mathematical notation rather than Mathematica code.  This is also a question that would fit better in math.stackexchange.com, since it doesn't have any scientific computation in it.

Answer (score 1):

I am happy to report that the problem is solved in Mathematica by Christoph Koutschan by using his add-on package "HolonomicFunctions" (https://www3.risc.jku.at/research/combinat/software/ergosum/RISC/HolonomicFunctions.html.

The problem is solved by computing recurrences for both expressions and showing that they coincide.

This relates to
https://oeis.org/A051708

Wolframalpha confirms that the recurrence obtained by Christoph Koutschan for both expressions

```mathematica
f[1]=2, f[2]=14, 9*n*f[n] + (-14 - 10*n)*f[1 + n] + (2 + n)*f[2 + n] == 0
```

gives

```
n | f(n)

1 | 2

2 | 14

3 | 106

4 | 838

5 | 6802

6 | 56190

7 | 470010

...
```

which are correct values for
https://oeis.org/A051708

So as the conclusion it follows that both:

the formula obtained byMariusz Iwaniuk

$$(-1)^n*((-4*n^2 - 16*n - 28)*JacobiP[-1 + n, -1 - 2*n, 2, -1/2] + JacobiP[-2 + n, -2*n, 3, -1/2]*(3 + n)*(-1 + n))*4^n/(48*(1 + n)*n)$$

and the recurrence obtained by Christoph Koutschan

$$ f[1]=2, f[2]=14, 9*n*f[n] + (-14 - 10*n)*f[1 + n] + (2 + n)*f[2 + n] == 0$$

rightfully belong to
https://oeis.org/A051708